1980s movie villain with a cybernetic claw that sprays acid
I watched this cheesy movie on tv when I was a kid in the early 90's. It's probably from the 80's. I believe it was post-apocalyptic. People rode around in a desert in dune-buggy type vehicles. They may have had laser weapons. 
The scene I specifically remember was where the villain killed an innocent old man with some sort of acidic liquid sprayed from his cybernetic claw hand, probably because he helped the hero in some way.  I think the old man was the father of the hero's girlfriend.  The villain broke a large crystal, or maybe the plot had something to do with these crystals. 
I thought this movie was Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone, because the villian had claw hands in that, but it's not.  This has been annoying me for two decades. 

Sounds like the Mad-Max-like film Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn from 1983:

The movie portrays the story of a space ranger named Dogen (played by Jeffrey Byron), who is in search of an intergalactic criminal with supernatural powers named Jared-Syn (played by Michael Preston).
The movie opens with Dogen attacked by a "skybike" (a one-man, open-cockpit flying machine), piloted by a nomad. Dogen shoots down the bike and finds one of Syn's crystals on the pilot's body. Carved into the crystal is a symbol of a dead tree. Dogen next finds a murdered prospector, whose young daughter Dhyana (Kelly Preston) saw him killed by Baal (R. David Smith), Jared Syn's half-cyborg son. Baal sprayed the man with a green liquid that caused a nightmare dream-state, in which Syn appeared and executed him with a crystal. 

You can see the villain's metal claw that shoots acid (and the dune buggy vehicles) in the trailer:




That's the one. This has been a burden on my mind for years. Walt, you are a wizard.
